# How to order a set in Kusto KQL/Kusto/Data Explorer

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

When I apply an 'order by' command to a query prior making sets the order does not stick.
How do I alphabetize the resulting set in the query below:

```
datatable (CaseNumber:string, AmendmentNumber:string, AmendmentNumberRaw:string, AmendmentType:string)
[
  '5-5-00a000b113z', 'T155', 'T155', 'Non-CTM'
, '5-5-00a000b113z', 'A156', 'A156', 'Non-CTM'
, '5-5-00a000b113z', 'M157', 'M157', 'Non-CTM'
]
| sort by AmendmentNumber asc
| summarize make_set(AmendmentNumber) by CaseNumber
```

Result:

5-5-00a000b113z ["T155","A156","M157"]

Expected Result:

5-5-00a000b113z ["A156","M157","T155"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for sorting a collection, you could use either of the following functions:

- [`array_sort_asc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arraysortascfunction)
- [`array_sort_desc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arraysortdescfunction)

for example:

```
datatable (CaseNumber:string, AmendmentNumber:string, AmendmentNumberRaw:string, AmendmentType:string)
[
  '5-5-00a000b113z', 'T155', 'T155', 'Non-CTM'
, '5-5-00a000b113z', 'A156', 'A156', 'Non-CTM'
, '5-5-00a000b113z', 'M157', 'M157', 'Non-CTM'
]
| summarize arr = make_set(AmendmentNumber) by CaseNumber
| extend sorted_asc = array_sort_asc(arr), sorted_desc = array_sort_desc(arr)
```

| CaseNumber | arr | sorted_asc | sorted_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5-5-00a000b113z | [ "T155", "A156", "M157" ] | [ "A156", "M157", "T155" ] | [ "T155", "M157", "A156" ] |